# XamarinForms : System.MissingFieldException: Field 'Xamarin.Forms.Slider.MinimumTrackColorProperty' not found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to compile and run an app that is working fine in the iOS simulator, but with Android I'm receiving

"System.MissingFieldException: Field 'Xamarin.Forms.Slider.MinimumTrackColorProperty' not found."

when trying to put it through the simulator.

Any idea why it doesn't like me setting the MinimumTrackColor?

Comment: Max|MinimumTrackColorProperty, etc... was added earlier this year, do you have the same Xamarin.Forms package version installed in your Xamarin.Android application project?

Comment: You were right, I've needed to upgrade to the development branch. The stable branch doesn't contain it for Android. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the stable version of Xamarin.Forms for Android doesn't include that property.

I've upgraded it to the development branch, and now it doesn't throw an error but the colors are still off. I'm guessing this is just part of the dev process of the nugget.

Thank you, SushiHangover.

Comment: I would report any issues you have with those features on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues (the original PR for those features: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1781)